# How can I make Devise immediately inform user of expired password reset token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

If a user requests 2 password reset links in a row, then only the most recent one is valid.

If a user clicks on the older one, they are not immediately informed of the token being invalid. They are asked to type in the new password twice. Only upon hitting submit are they informed that the token is not valid.

Is there a standard way to change this behavior, so the user is immediately informed that they used the wrong link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a bit surprised to find out that this is standard behavior - thanks for bringing it up! I would probably use a custom controller that inherits from `Devise::PasswordsController` and simply override `:edit`. The trouble is we're working with an abstract user (since no user is actually authenticated at this point), so we can't check it against a particular token in the database, and we have to check whether the given token exists.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  before_filter :validate_reset_password_token, only: :edit

  private
    def validate_reset_password_token
      recoverable = resource_class.find_by_reset_password_token(params[:reset_password_token])
      redirect_to root_path unless (recoverable && recoverable.reset_password_period_valid?)
    end
end
```

This will redirect unless a user exists with the token passed. You can handle the redirection/error display however you wish.

Finally, in your routes file, change the controller used by devise for passwords:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { passwords: "passwords" }
```

Caveats:

- I have not tested this (but I might look into it tomorrow).
- There may be some additional security issues to consider - could someone realistically gain access to a random account? (probably not; Devise uses a similar method of locating a model instance using the reset token in `reset_password_by_token`)

By the way, there is no way to tell them that they used the wrong link and they should click the other one, as there is no way to positively identify them in the first place, and therefore no way to know that they have already generated another valid token.

Comment: "there is no way to tell them that they used the wrong link and they should click the other one, as there is no way to positively identify them in the first place"... true, but that's definitely going to be the most common scenario, so we can still give helpful guidance. "whoops, this link isn't valid. maybe because you've done a newer password reset since this one?" or something

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed too, thanks. One thing that I had to change though was to compare the digested token instead (because the actual token is not stored in the DB) `digested_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, params[:reset_password_token])` then `recoverable = resource_class.find_by_reset_password_token(digested_token)`

Answer (score 0):

There is another safety solution for this question;

```
class User::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def update
    super do |resource|
      # Jump to super code
      next unless resource.errors.any?
      token_errors = resource.errors.details[:reset_password_token]
      expired_error = token_errors.select { |detail| detail[:error] == :expired }
      # Jump to super code
      next unless expired_error.present?
      message = resource.errors.full_messages_for(:reset_password_token).join(',')
      return redirect_to new_user_password_path, alert: message
    end
  end
end
```